# Not Running Groovy task on building android application

Tags: java, android, groovy, build.gradle

I got a code from internet to copy and paste *module jar* to another location and renaming it.

```
task copyCloudSdkJar(type: Copy) {
    from('WiSe-Cloud-SDK/build/intermediates/bundles/default/')
    into('WiSe-Cloud-SDK/release/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'WiSe-Cloud-SDK.jar')
}
```

The above given is the task I was written. And it is working when we manually executing task.

> **Problem**
>
> But When I rebuilding/building/cleaning my application the task is not running automatically

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this task in dependencies for build task.
For example:

```
task copyCloudSdkJar(type: Copy) {
    ...
}

// if you want to run before build
build.dependsOn copyCloudSdkJar

// if you want to run after build
build.finalizedBy copyCloudSdkJar
```

Comment: No luck. It is not working. Please note that it is my library project. Thank you for your reply